# Elastic update_by_query inside array

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch, update-by-query

I have an array which looks like this:

```
"_source": {
    "dateCreated": "2023-07-12",
    "sources": [
      {
        "1": null,
        "lastUpdateDate": "2023-08-10T11:12:36.9848505",
        "postedDate": "2023-08-10T10:38:57.9440773"
```

**How can I update postedDate from sources array?**

I've managed to update dateCreated with this query:

```
POST index/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.dateCreated='2023-07-12'",
    "lang": "painless"
  },
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "_id": [
"12345"
]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this by accessing the array:

```
ctx._source.sources[0].postedDate='2023-07-12'
```